# Variables which only changes over time in fixed effects

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Suppose we have a model which relates state level consumption of alcohol to state level hospital expenditures:

$$
\text{Hospital expenditure}_{i,t} = \beta_1 \text{alcohol consumption}_{i,t} + \dotso + a_i + u_{i,t}
$$

Where $i$ is an index for the state, and $t$ are the time periods (years) $t \in (1, 2, \dotso,T)$, and $a_i$ are the fixed effects. In this model one might think to add to GDP, suppose that GDP is only avaible at the country level and not state level. Does it make sense to include it? I.e. the GDP variable only changes over $t$, not over $i$.

One drawback of course is that time dummies cannot be included, since they would be perfectly correlated with time variable. Does it then make sense to use trends instead?

Comment: The point of including time dummies is to absorb shocks which are common to all states in each time period. Adding countrywide GDP would therefore just be absorbed in the time dummies, hence there's no need to collect such variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using data from just one country?

If you're thinking of using GDP to measure an economic shock to hospital expenditure (say, that was a bad year, so people will demand more/less health), then definitely use GDP growth (instead of GDP levels!)

However, provided you have enough data (and are not interested in the GDP growth coefficient), it usually makes more sense to use a time dummy (not a trend), since other things (not related to GDP growth) might have happened that year that provided a shock to hospital expenditures on all counties.

There are of course many measures at the county level you could use, but without knowing your objectives it's difficult to say.